# Executing zgrep with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, grep

I need to execute the zgrep command through a node.js app. I have managed to add the grep command to my app like so:

```
const grep = require('grep1');

grep(['greptext', './logs/file], function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err || stderr) {
            console.log(err, stderr);
        } else {
            console.log(stdout);
        }
    });
```

This works fine for text files but I need to do the same for gz files using the zgrep command. Is there an npm package that can do this for me?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do this using the child_process package. Sample implementation below:

```
exec = require('child_process').exec;

child = exec('zgrep \'search text\' ./logs/file',
        function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
            console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
            if (error !== null) {
                console.log('exec error: ' + error);
            }
        });
```